# How to Show Qualified Digital Certificates By Using Java

Tags: java, windows, x509certificate

I created an application that e-sign PDF documents by using Qualified Digital Certificates in Java. The problem is, user want to display his/her certificate before e-singing document.

I want to show this information using Windows Certificate Display which open .crt files. But I can't seem to find anything about this.

So, how can I show certificates to users with Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just needed to open that certificate file and **double-click** it by using `java.awt.Desktop` library as shown below:

```
File file = new File("myCertificate.crt");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```